# How to read KiCad page settings values from a python BOM generation script

Tags: python, kicad

I am using KiCad V6 and have modified the bill of materials generation script `bom_csv_grouped_by_value.py` to produce BOM's only containing the information I am interested in, and formatted how I like. These currently have the filename matching the KiCad project name, e.g. for a project called "valve-tester" it would be `valve-tester.xlsx`. I would like to be able to read the "Title" and "Revision" fields from the schematic Page Settings to name the BOM something more meaningful, e.g. `BOM for Valve Tester revC 17-11-22.xlsx`.

["Title" and "Revision" fields](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ta7gH.png)

Does anyone know how I can extract this information from a python script, or somehow automate passing it in as an argument? Any help would be greatly appreciated!

So far I am thinking one option would be to have the user manually enter the desired filename each time you run the script, although this is sub-optimal and I am aiming to automate it.

Answer (score 0):

Turns out you can just read the `.kicad_sch` schematic file as a text file and the information is all there, e.g

```
with open ("valve-tester.kicad_sch", "r") as myfile:
    data = myfile.read().splitlines()
    title_line = data[7]
    revision_line = data[9]
```